# How to get a document in mongodb only if at least 3 columns have non null values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in MongoDB say STUDENT with attributes id, name, standard, marks, average. Now I want to write a query so that I get only those documents where at least 3 attributes contain non-null values.

All those documents that contain non null value in (name, standard, marks) or (name,marks,average) or (name,standard,marks,average) or (id, name, standard, marks, average) should be printed. But if any document contains only (name,standard) as non null or (standard,marks) should be ignored.

Comment: This needs a much clearer example in your question. Include some sample documents that meet and fail your conditions with your expected result.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: You cannot do this without some physical logic either using the aggregation framework or some other method currently. MongoDB can't report within query results how many columns matched. I don't think sparse indexes will work here either

Comment: Actual document examples would make it clearer to a wider audience. Remember that not everyone sees what you see. Your job is to clearly present your case to the world that is not working at your desk.

Comment: Well that being said, 4 $or statements would work

Comment: @Sammaye `$ifNull` in the aggregation framework does exactly that where specified fields do not exist.

Comment: @NeilLunn Indeed however that would require a non-indexed collection scan

Comment: @Sammaye Horrible. Yes agreed, provided there was nothing else to match on. A plain query is always best, but that is why I am asking the OP to post some real example documents and an expected result. Good clear questions get up-votes, so it helps them as well as gets the answer they need.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said that given "students" documents like this:

```js
{ name: "a", standard: "b", marks: 10 },
{ name: "b", marks: 5, average: 2 },
{ id: 2, name: "c", marks: 10, average: 7 },
{ name: "c", standard: "b" },
{ standard: "c", marks: 3 }
```

Then "ideally" you would do something like this:

```js
db.students.find({
    "$or": [
        { 
           "$and": [
                { "name": { "$exists": true } },
                { "name": { "$ne": null } },
                { "standard": { "$exists": true } },
                { "standard": { "$ne": null } },
                { "marks": { "$exists": true } },
                { "marks": { "$ne": null } },
           ],
        },
        {
           "$and": [
                { "name": { "$exists": true } },
                { "name": { "$ne": null } },
                { "marks": { "$exists": true } },
                { "marks": { "$ne": null } },
                { "average": { "$exists": true } },
                { "average": { "$ne": null } }
           ],
        },
        {
           "$and": [
                { "name": { "$exists": true } },
                { "name": { "$ne": null } },
                { "marks": { "$exists": true } },
                { "marks": { "$ne": null } },
                { "standard": { "$exists": true } },
                { "standard": { "$ne": null } },
                { "average": { "$exists": true } },
                { "average": { "$ne": null } }
           ],
        },
        {
           "$and": [
                { "id": { "$exists": true } },
                { "id": { "$ne": null } },
                { "name": { "$exists": true } },
                { "name": { "$ne": null } },
                { "marks": { "$exists": true } },
                { "marks": { "$ne": null } },
                { "standard": { "$exists": true } },
                { "standard": { "$ne": null } },
                { "average": { "$exists": true } },
                { "average": { "$ne": null } }
           ],
        }
    ]
})
```

Which excludes those last two documents.

Also in modern MongoDB 2.6 and greater versions you get index intersection, or a version of such in 2.4 versions considering the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operand. So you can index like so:

```js
 db.student.ensureIndex({ "name": 1, "standard": 1, "marks": 1 })
 db.student.ensureIndex({ "name": 1, "marks": 1, "average": 1 })
 db.student.ensureIndex({ "name": 1, "marks": 1, "standard": 1, "average": 1 })
 db.student.ensureIndex({ "id": 1, "name": 1, "marks": 1, "standard": 1, "average": 1 })
```

That can add up to a lot of "index" space usage, so the means may outweigh the ends in this case.

Of course for a more flexible approach to determining this (though not as fast) then you can approach the aggregation framework:

```js
db.students.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "id": { "$ifNull": [ "$id", null ] },
        "name": { "$ifNull": [ "$name", null ] },
        "marks": { "$ifNull": [ "$marks", null ] },
        "standard": { "$ifNull": [ "$standard", null ] },
        "average": { "$ifNull": [ "$average", null ] },
        "fields": {
            "$add": [
                { "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$id", null ] }, 1, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$name", null ] }, 1, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$marks", null ] }, 1, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$standard", null ] }, 1, 0 ] },
                { "$cond": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$average", null ] }, 1, 0 ] },
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "fields": { "$gte": 3 } } }
])
```

Which is essentially the more "literal" interpretation of your question if limited by the aggregation framework constraint of actually needing to declare **all** of those "fields" that are possible.

The [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator is the one doing the "heavy lifting", by replacing "non-existant" or `null` fields with a `null` value for evaluation. You could also hopefully "try" to filter with a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in the initial pipeline stage much as was done in the first query to reduce the input.

The final real catch comes in if you just have **too many* varying field combinations to specify in either form and you just need to know that "three" or more of your fields essentially exist or are not null.

This approach comes down to using [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) form of evaluation, which is the least efficient way to handle the general query, but it is the most flexible since the JavaScript code can handle these situations:

```js
db.students.find(
    function() {
        var count = 0;
        for ( var k in this ) {
            if ( ( k != null) && ( k != "_id") ) {
                count++;
                if ( count >= 3 )
                    break;
            }
        }
        return ( count >= 3 );
    }
)
```

So while the last forms "looks" simple, it is actually pretty horrible as there is no way to avoid what essentially ends up as a "full collection scan", as all the fields in each document get evaluated for the conditions in JavaScript. Well at least until the count of "three" is reached.

That gives you a few approaches. Hopefully the first one actually suits.